# Why use the j_username and SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME variables?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, spring-security

Why do this?

```
<input type="text" name="j_username" value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME}">
```

instead of this?

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="">
```

What's the value of the j_username and SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME variables?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`j_username` and `j_password` are standardized names in the Java Servlet specification, so the application servers (or servlet containers) know about them and can perform **container authentication**, independently of the application. This allows for example single-sign on into multiple webapps deployed in the same application server. See chapter "SRV 12.5.3 Form Based Authentication" in [JSR-154](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr154/index.html)

The Spring Security constant is just a convenience for users, so they don't have to re-enter their username, if Spring Security recognizes them it automatically suggests the username.