# Can we pass the entered username to authentication failure url in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Can we pass the entered username to authentication failure url in spring security in case of authentication failure by unmatching password?

Comment: This is a very confusing question.  Can you rephrase it to make it more clear what the problem is?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are asking, how do we get the username in case of authentication failure, it is available in a special spring-security constant SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME.

This [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791484/why-use-the-j-username-and-spring-security-last-username-variables) could be useful reference.